# Returning Value in Functional Programming

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I started exploring "Functional Programming" using Scala .
I'd like to know how can we return a value in functional programming. I wrote a recursive function

```
def calculateSum(mainlist: List[Int]): Int = {
      def Sum(curentElem:Int = 0,thislist:List[Int],): Int = {
       if (list.isEmpty) curentElem
       else loop(curentElem + thislist.head, thislist.tail)
      //curentElem
     }
      Sum((List(0,1,2,3,4)))
      println ("returned from Sum : " + curentElem)

  }
```

- Should I just add "curentElem" in the last line of the function (as I am doing in the commented line) !

UPDATE: 
I just solved the problem :

```
object HelloScala  {    
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {     
      val s = sum(0, List(0,1,2,3,4))
      println("returned from Sum : " + s )
    }  

def sum(currentElem: Int, thislist: List[Int]): Int = {
      thislist match {
        case Nil => currentElem
        case head :: tail => sum(currentElem + head, tail)
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: You probably mean `println (Sum .... )`as `currentElem` is not defined outside the Sum function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to print the result, then you can do it like that

```
def calculateSum(mainlist: List[Int]): Int = {
   def sum(currentElem: Int, thislist: List[Int]): Int = {
      if (thislist.isEmpty) curentElem
      else sum(currentElem + thislist.head, thislist.tail)
      //curentElem
   }
   val s = sum(0, mainlist)
   println("returned from Sum : " + s)
   s
}
```

If you don't:

```
def calculateSum(mainlist: List[Int]): Int = {
   def sum(currentElem: Int, thislist: List[Int]): Int = {
      if (thislist.isEmpty) curentElem
      else sum(currentElem + thislist.head, thislist.tail)
      //curentElem
   }
   sum(0, mainlist)
}
```

A way to use pattern matching (which you will use quite often in scala):

```
def calculateSum2(mainlist: List[Int]): Int = {
    def sum(currentElem: Int, thislist: List[Int]): Int = {
      thislist match {
        case Nil => currentElem
        case head :: tail => sum(currentElem + head, tail)
      }
    }
    sum(0, mainlist)
}
```

`Nil` is an empty List.

Comment: Thanks ! I got a wired error :  found.error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
   println("returned from Sum : " + s);
          ^
one error found

Comment: I made a few changes. Have a look.

Comment: The "problem" with that solution is that one can pass the initial value for the `currentElem`. e.g. I could call `sum(1, mainlist)` which would result in the sum + 1. You want `currentElem` to always be 0. Therefore do something like the `calculateSum2`, where there is only one parameter (the List).